# ReferenceError: dc is not defined, even after importing d3,dc and crossfilter in order

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

In the angular app that I am building with dc.js and leaflet, I have done the following imports in component.ts in the order of d3, crossfilter2, dc, leaflet.

And in index.html I have the cdn for dc-leaflet.js

But in the console I am getting the errors:

> ReferenceError: dc is not defined
>       at dc-leaflet.js:10
>       at dc-leaflet.js:124

and

> ReferenceError: dc is not defined
>       at scripts.bundle.js:10
>       at scripts.bundle.js:124

Comment: In the browser's dev console (F12), check the Network tab for load order/timing issues (or errors). Some external libs return a script that loads other modules -- angular may be trying to use one of them before it is fully loaded...

Comment: Again, this sounds like module loader problems - some are very strict and keep every module completely separate (no globals) unless they declare their dependencies on each other. If you know how to choose the module loader, try choosing a really basic one that just lets JS be JS.

Answer (score 1):

So,

I think you need the cdn's for leaflet, crossfilter, and d3 also.

dc.js is kindof a plugin that links all of the libs together.

You an look at these examples : [dc.js leaflet es6](https://github.com/Ry10p/crossfilter-geo-input)

these are using ES6 imports (kinda work like script tags).

```
    import * as thing from 'thing';
```

AND

I also have included a **cdn script tag** **version** of the project.

FURTHER, I recommend that you register the libs with webpack or whatever you use.  If that doesn't work use StencilJS, [fits in angular](https://stenciljs.com/docs/framework-integration)

I personally have gotten the libs to work inside StencilJS.